# Proper Order to Incorporate Ingredients in Pound Cake

Tags: cake

When making a pound cake, this is the usual order I use:

(1) Cream butter
(2) Add sugar and beat it in
(3) Gradually add eggs and beat them in
(4) Gently fold in flour, alternating with liquid (if there is liquid in the recipe)

I would like to try separating the egg yolks and whites. In what order should I then add the ingredients? Please include an answer for recipes with and without liquid.

Comment: To what end? Is there a desired effect you're going for?

Comment: @ChefAndy Nothing in particular. I just want to see if whipping the egg whites separately produces a cake that I prefer. I'm not sure when to add all the ingredients though.

Comment: A heavy batter w/ whipped egg whites can end up turning into a souffle.  You might want to look at recipes for chiffon cake instead.  Or any other less dense cake.  ps.  asking for recipes generally gets the question shut down.  You need to ask about technique, not recipes.

Answer (score 5):

What you're probably looking for is a hybrid between your pound cake and a [seperated sponge cake](http://www.joyofbaking.com/FoamCakesTechniques.html), in which you'd probably want to cream the yolks, butter, and sugar, mix your egg white foam with flour, and then fold the flour/foam into the yolk/butter/egg mixture. My gut says the amount of butter in a pound cake will kill the foam structure of the egg whites immediately, but what the heck... experimenting is always fun.

Another option would be to make a regular separated sponge cake, and then use melted butter as kind of a soaking liquid like you would with a genoise. Might provide the fluffier, yet super buttery texture you're looking for. You could also just make [genoise](https://www.williams-sonoma.com/recipe/genoise.html), but it's certainly not as rich as pound cake.

Answer (score 1):

Adding beaten egg whites separately is a well known technique and has been used in my family for decades. It produces a lighter, more open crumb. The order is to follow the procedure outlined by the OP, substituting yolks for whole eggs, then as step 5, fold in the stiffly beaten whites. Works great!

Comment: This is the method I would use, beaten egg whites should be added last to avoid them breaking